# How to use Pear's File_CSV

Tags: csv, pear

How to open a CSV file for reading with Pear's File_CSV library?

Comment: please close the question if you answered yourself. you could also add the answer you posted as answer and accept it :)

Comment: You are right, sorry about that. I have done as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here:

```
<?php

require_once 'File/CSV.php';

$csv_file = __DIR__ . "/file_name.csv";

$config = File_CSV::discoverFormat($csv_file);
while ($res = File_CSV::readQuoted($csv_file, $config)) {

    print_r($res);
}
```